# Order of Magnitude for Photon Induction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, electromagnetic-induction

What does magnetic induction look like when we imagine just one photon passing by? I'm imagining some sort of coil wrapped around the edge of a waveguide or something so that it picks up some of the transverse magnetic field. Would the photon lose energy through such induction? How could we estimate both the signal induced in the  coil and the change in the photon's energy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is right for an electron isn’t right for a photon.

An electron has a charge and moves with a velocity between zero and the speed of light. Loosing its kinetic energy, the electron could do work, be this a magnetic induction or the production of heat. But the electron still be the subatomic particle.

A photon moves always with the speed of light and its energy is not consumable in parts. (It has no kinetic energy because it is claimed, that it has no rest mass. But it has a momentum, and photons generate a recoil when they get absorbed.) From the emission until its absorption the photon is a indivisible unit.

Anyway, your question is an interesting. Because photons don’t move in straight line in some cases. Firstly they following a geodesic path. Means, that changes in the gravitational potential leads to the deflection of the photon in the direction of the higher gravitational potential. Secondly, in some distance to body (best recognisable for sharp edges) the photon gets deflected too. Some interaction between the photon (it’s oscillating electric and magnetic field) and the subatomic particles (mostly the electrons) of the edge takes place.

But, since the energy content of the photon stays unremained after such interaction, it should be impossible to extract energy (or even a signal) from this interaction. Indeed strange.

Never heard, that a signal was generated from photons without the consumption of these photons. Only if someone else could report about such a signal, the real existing deflection of photons on edges (or a coil or whatsoever) will not be strange more from the point of view of your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm confused about how you say that the photon's energy is not consumable in parts. In Compton scattering, for instance, doesn't the photon lose energy when its frequency is downshifted after scattering off an electron?

Comment: “A photon γ with wavelength λ collides with an electron e in an atom, which is treated as being at rest. The collision causes the electron to recoil, and a ••new•• photon γ' with wavelength λ' emerges at angle θ from the photon's incoming path. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering#Description_of_the_phenomenon